# Looking for linear solenoid actuators less than 2 cm in length

Tags: solenoid, actuator

Do such parts exist?  Are they cheap?

I want to take a sheet of plastic and cover both sides with solenoids, some aligned in the X  direction and some aligned in the Y direction.  With at least a 10x10 grid, I can selectively turn the solenoids on and off to flex the sheet into millions of unique shapes.

Comment: Millions is an understatement. You have 1 267 650 600 228 229 401 496 703 205 376 possible combinations.

Comment: Sort of like adaptive optics in a space telescope.  Could be interesting to implement in a hall of mirrors in a fun house.

Answer (score 3):

[This one](http://www.theleeco.com/leeweb2.nsf/pds69.pdf)

[image]

is 1 cm long. Short enough? I don't have a price, but the cheapest solenoids at Digikey are 9 dollar at 100s. I expect the miniatures to be more expensive.

Comment: Hmm that looks like a valve to me, not an actuator.  I'm pretty sure none of the visible parts move.

Comment: @nialsh - Mm, I don't know. If the pins in the center are flow in- and outputs I expect the thinner cylinder to shift to open and close the valve. That's solenoid action, right?